# Trouble saving image on a django apache mod_wsgi configuration

Tags: django, permissions

The Mod WSGI configuration

```
 WSGIDaemonProcess bangtestwsgi.max140.com python-path=/home/bangwsgi/alpha:/home/bangwsgi/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages

WSGIProcessGroup bangtestwsgi.max140.com

Alias /media/ /home/bangwsgi/alpha/media/

<Directory /home/bangwsgi/alpha/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/bangwsgi/alpha/alpha/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/bangwsgi/alpha/alpha>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

The error:

> OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/home/bangwsgi/alpha/media/img/FLOW.png'

The user "bangwsgi" owns all the directories related with the project i.e. inside /home/bangwsgi/

What could be going wrong? What other permissions can I give? What can I try?

I would be grateful for any kind of breakthrough on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel silly writing the answer myself

I had to change the first line in the configuration to include -

```
WSGIDaemonProcess bangtestwsgi.max140.com user=bangwsgi python-path=/home/bangwsgi/alpha:/home/bangwsgi/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Apache was running it as root and not as the user who owned the project directories. Duh.